# How to know if a browser tab focused when it's loaded with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, focus

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648120/is-there-a-way-track-the-focus-on-tab-with-javascript). But it doesn't work when a page is initially loaded because the blur event will not fire if for example the user opens the page in a new tab and it doesn't get focus.

So what would be the best way to do this?

For now, my temporary solution is to assume the tab is blurred when it loads and bind a function to the mouseover event of the document that will set it to focused. But that won't work if the user does not have their mouse on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the code you linked to, set the default to blurred:

```
<div id="blurDiv"></div>

<script>

var updateStatus = (function() {

  // Private stuff
  var el = document.getElementById('blurDiv');

  // The updateStatus function
  return function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var evtType = evt.type;
    var state;

    // Determine state
    if (evtType == 'load' || evtType == 'blur' || evtType == 'focusout' ) {
      state = 'blurred';
    } else {
      state = 'focussed';
    }

    // Now do something...
    el.innerHTML += '<br>' + state
  };
})();

window.onload = updateStatus;

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = updateStatus;
    document.onfocusout = updateStatus;
} else {
    window.onfocus = updateStatus;
    window.onblur = updateStatus;
}

</script>
```

IE seems to fire lots of extra events, every time something gets focus, there is first a blur then a focus so clicking on things in the page has lots of spurious blur/focus pairs.

Comment: This doesn't check anything when it's loaded. It just assumes it's blurred.

Comment: There is nothing to check, the script is dependent on bubbling events. When focus events fire on the window or document is inconsistent between browswers, there is no robust method, however after the first one, they are reasonably predictable.
Oh, it has nothing to do with the cursor, it is do do wtih focus. you can change focus in many ways, not just the cursor.

Comment: What I'm saying is in the beginning of the script, you do need to check if the tab is either focused or blurred because the events won't fire until the tab either gets focused or blurred. And that will not happen in the beginning if the tab is already focused/blurred. Your script assumes a tab will always be blurred when it's loaded. When it isn't always true.

Comment: And what I'm saying is you can't check, there is nothing to check.

Comment: You're saying this question is unanswerable?

Comment: I suppose so. There is no property to check, so you have to wait for an event. If the browser doesn't fire one at an appropriate time (there is no standard and different browsers seem to fire focus events at different times), you're out of luck.