# Event for browser tab hidden/shown?

Tags: javascript, tabs, focus, dom-events

Is there any DOM event for when the browser tab loses/gains focus? I know there are the `blur` and `focus` events on `window`, but they also fire when the browser window as a whole loses focus. The browser might then be still visible to the user. Of course such an event would be browser specific, but that's ok.

The reason why I want this is because I run animations that might consume quite some CPU time. When the browser tab is not visible there is no reason to continue animating. Now I know that modern browsers reduce the timer resolution of background tabs, but I could actually pause the animation, so that no CPU time whatsoever is consumed.

In case you are wondering, this is what I'm writing:
http://panzi.github.com/Browser-Ponies/

Comment: So are you asking how to tell when a tab stops being visible, or stops having focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least Google Chrome supports a `webkitvisibilitychange` event and a `document.webkitHidden` property. See the [visibility API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility). But it seems only to fire when the shown tab changes, not when the whole window is minimized. There also seems to be a `visibilitychange` event for Internet Explorer, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Firefox now also has a visibility API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: caniuse reports excellent support now (http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility) for the visibility API

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I believe you'll find is the top answer here:

[Is there a way track the focus on tab with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648120/is-there-a-way-track-the-focus-on-tab-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Now they have exactly what was needed: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: As I mentioned in my own answer: This doesn't fire when the window is minimized/restored. But yeah, better than nothing.