# Jquery / Javascript: Is possible to know when page is focussed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, handler

my goal is to auto-refresh some components with jquery when the "page tab" is focussed. I have a "sort of cart" and i want to auto-update it even if you are displaying my site from more than 1 tab.
Also, i'm trying to make it work from an iframe inside a page!

is this possible or i must use some timer to auto-refresh periodically?

edit: after reading the solution i made it work once for every focus, don't know if it's the best solution but it gets the job done :D

```
var focusPage = false;
var firstFocus = false;
$(window).focus(function () {
                focusPage = true;
                if (firstFocus) {
                    firstFocus = false;
                    //BAM! Refresh your stuff
                }
            });
$(window).blur(function () {
                    focusPage = false;
                    firstFocus = true;
                });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479305/event-for-browser-tab-hidden-shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this seems to work well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).focus(function () {
        console.log("bam!");
    })
});
```

Comment: there is a way to get that called only once the first time my window gets the focus?

Comment: If you want it to cancel after the first bam, use `$(window).unbind('focus');` within the focus callback.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch `focus` event on window. 
Try to use:

```
$(window).focus(function(){
   //refresh your div;
});
```

Comment: thats not working for me :( i'm trying it with an alert inside the focus function but it's not triggered :( even tried with 'body' and '#body' but no result :(

Answer (score 1):

Just what you have written above can be achieved by this

`window.onblur= function() {
         window.onfocus= function () {  location.reload(true); }
};`

It will do things just once. You can reduce the code by this call.