# Weird "quantum" TIMER/TIMEOUT phenomenon in android

Tags: javascript, android, settimeout

I have a webpage that retrieves the GPS positions of buses, and display those in a map. It retrieves the positions once every 60 seconds through a loop like this:

```
function startLinhaLoop() {
  if (!timer) {
    loopLinha();
    timer = setInterval(function() {loopLinha()}, 60000);
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, you can see it working [here](http://luis.impa.br/riobas/index.html?linha=409,416,410,309&az=260&center=-22.94732,-43.24023&zoom=13&ponto=-22.94273,-43.20201&avmin=2&avmax=50).

I put the whole thing in an app for android, that I use regularly. One of its features is that, if the screen of the phone is off, it speaks how long the 3 closest buses will take to arrive. So, once each 60 seconds, you hear "Buses in x, y, and z seconds". The web version also speaks if the page is not active.

This app always worked perfectly, as the webpage. But in the last two months (after I updated Android Studio) it began to fail (no idea why): the loop takes much longer than 60 secs, and it is even irregular. It speaks now, then 3 minutes later, then 8, then 2, then 12... I have tried to see what happens, and the script is not getting stalled, nor waiting for a download (the download has a `timeout`). It is simply like instead of `timeout 60000` it was `timeout random`.

But the really strange phenomena happens when I try to debug the app: as soon as I connect `adb` wireless and begin looking at `adb logcat`, the `timer` works perfectly. I stop `adb` server, and the timer goes crazy again. Connect, fine. Disconnect, crazy... It is like the `timer` knows that I am looking to it. A Schrodinger timer. :) During all the time, the wifi is connected and the phone makes noises when receiving whatsapp or whatever, so internet is fully active always.

I know that this question is not very specific and kind of vague (sorry for that), but maybe someone has heard of something like this before. Maybe this is a bug in some recent release of Android Studio?

BTW, I am working in a rooted Android 4.4 in a Galaxy Note 4. In my wife phone it works as expected.

Comment: I think for a perfect solution, you should convert it into native java...

Comment: Clear the timer when the window loses focus.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479305/event-for-browser-tab-hidden-shown

Comment: @Jonasw: No way. It's a 900 page javascript. And, more importantly, I don't want to maintain two separate codes. That's a road to disaster.

Comment: Yeah, but android goes to sleep (and wakes up sometimes), you need to control this wakeup to get the desired behaviour...

Comment: @Jonasw: I don't think it is a wakeup thing, since I get whatsapp noises all the time while the app should be responding. And with tasker I set `Sleep never` while at home.

Comment: Yeah, whatsapp wakes up, doeant mean that your js is running...

Comment: @Mottie: you mean to do a `clearTimeout(timer)`?

Comment: Yes, but you're using `setInterval`, so stop it using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

Comment: @Mottie: I'm not sure what you mean. If I `clearInterval`, the timer loop just stops. You mean to restart the whole thing?

Comment: Clear the interval when the tab loses focus, then restart the interval when focus is regained; unless you want the app to keep talking...

Comment: @Mottie: Yes, this is exactly what I want: when the screen is off, I want it to keep talking to me. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522580/145346

Comment: @Mottie: Thanks, since the web version is working fine, I solved the thing with a `wakelock` (see my answer). But I will take your suggestion into account, I didn't know about `WebWorker`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a `wakelock` in the pure `java` part of my code:

```
PowerManager pm;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

public void onCreate(final Bundle onOreintChange) {
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    ....
```

and (not sure if this is necessary, just in case)

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    wakeLock.release();
    ...
```

For some reason that I don't understand, this was not needed before and now it is in my Android 4.4 (still not needed in my wife's Android 6.0). Certainly `adb` prevents the device sleep, that's why it worked fine during the debug. In other projects I tried `wakelock` before, but never worked as I expected.

Although I did not follow `@Jonas w` advice above exactly as he proposed, it made me give  `wakelock` another try. Thanks Jonas!